# MYSQL PHP - get float LIKE $float

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, where-clause, sql-like

I want to get rows with floats like my `$float`.

I used this code:

```
$float = $_GET['float'];

$requst = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floats WHERE float LIKE'$float.%%%%%%%'"));
```

then I echoed all the rows with while:

```
while ($r = $request) {

    echo $a['float'];

}
```

but the page doesn't show anything. (YES, I typed in the address bar `?float=34` and there are floats like `34.******` in the table.)

What is the problem?

(PHP version 5.2, MYSQL version 5.0)

Comment: Be careful using datatypes as column names.

Comment: You are working with only one result, put the `mysql_fetch_array` directly inside `while` in place of `$request`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$requst = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floats WHERE float LIKE'$float.%%%%%%%'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {

    echo $r['float'];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `select * from floats where floor(float) = $floor;`?

Comment: also, try properly concatenating your query string like so:  "select * from floats where floor(float) = ".$floor

Comment: Not if you're just matching the integer part

Comment: I wasn't really saying that directly to you ethr.  Your question (user107..) looks like it is asking us to query all floats that have the same whole number when you remove the decimals.  This solution would find those.

Comment: I agree; using `LIKE` forces MySQL to convert the column to a string for comparison which will affect performance

Answer (score 1):

Your variable already has a decimal point in it.

`"SELECT * FROM floats WHERE float LIKE '$float%'"`

If your float is 34.567 your statement executes as find like '34.567.%' which isn't finding any results.

Edit:
how about this then?

`"SELECT * FROM floats WHERE abs(float-$float)<1;"`

That will bring in anything within 1?

Having said that, although you can keep floats in mysql, it might be safer to keep them as decimals with a limited number of points after the decimal.