# get Get the float nearest other floats in array

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL PHP - get float LIKE $float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562165/mysql-php-get-float-like-float)

i have floats from database. here is my code:

```
$float = $_GET['float'];
$requst = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floats WHERE float LIKE'$float.%%%%%%%' AND float2 LIKE'$float2.%%%%%%%'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($requst)) {

    $array[] = $r['float'];

}
```

the code getting float from user name `$float` and floats from table in database and adding it to array .

how i can know what float in the array are the nearly to the `$float`?

Comment: how about something like `select * from floats order by float-$float limit 1`

Comment: I hope this is just some example code, because this is an SQL injection waiting to happen

Comment: Side note: what's with all the percent signs? One would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Lets cast provided float to float type to prevent sql injections
$float = (float) $_GET['float'];
$requst = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floats WHERE float LIKE'$float.%%%%%%%' AND float2 LIKE'$float2.%%%%%%%'");
$array = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($requst)) {
    // Lets store an array of differences between the provided float
    // and db floats, indexed by db float value
    $array[$r['float']] = abs($r['float'] - $float);
}
// Now lets sort the array by values(differences)
// keeping the keys intact
asort($array);
// The first key of the resulting array is the closest float to the provided float
$closest = array_pop(array_keys($array));
```

Comment: what it doing? you can say what the code doing?